# Promise doesn't work with node-dir readfiles

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I tried to use the node-dir module from Nodejs to read files from a directory, after all files are read I then send them to Redis, and finally shutdown the Redis connection, so I used Promise. However, the quitting connection to Redis line always gets to executed first, the "then" clause doesn't seem to wait till the Promise resolves, leading to connection being shut down before any persisting happens, may I seek your help?

```
new Promise((resolved, failed) => {
    nodeDir.readFiles(dirName, options, (err, file, nextCallback) => {
        if(err){throw err};
        //...logics to get key&value
        redisClient.set(key, value);
        nextCallback();
    });
    resolved(); //it finally resolves
    }).then(()=>{
    redisClient.quit(); //this line never waits, it always executes first
})
```

Comment: Please add the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: FYI, `fs.promises.readdir` returns a promise & is native in node. [fs.promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at a block of code similar to yours to find out what's going wrong here:

```
new Promise((resolved, failed) => {
   setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
      resolved(); 
   }).then(()=>{
   console.log("DONE");
})
```

In this case, the text "DONE" is printed immediately in the console.

However, if we write it like below, we'll get something different:

```
new Promise((resolved, failed) => {
   setTimeout(function(){
      resolved();
   }, 3000);  
   }).then(()=>{
   console.log("DONE");
})
```

In this case, "DONE" will be printed to the console after 3 seconds. You resolving the promise immediately, that's what is going wrong here. Just try it resolving once all the side-effects end. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the API of the module node-dir, it actually provides a form of readFiles that offers a callback which gets executed after all files are handled, I then modified my code to do the resolve there, it works as expected finally, thank you very much @Plabon Dutta!

the modified version

```
new Promise((resolved, failed) => {
  nodeDir.readFiles(dirName, (err, file, nextCallback) => {
    // file handling
  }, (err, files) => {
    resolved(); //here does the resolve
  });
}).then(()=>{
  redisClient.quit();
})
```

Comment: Can you post what you finished with?  Both the question and accepted answer place a then block where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Do you mean post a modified version of my code(the solution I took)? I have done that at the bottom of my latest comment already, sorry I'm new to using stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks, you posted what I wanted to review (helpful for future readers to understand the solution).

Comment: However, to "promise-ify" a callback-style function, you want to wrap it with a function that takes the same params except with no completion callback.  The job of the wrapper is to invoke the old style function and resolve the promise when the completion callback is called, *nothing else*.  So the `then` block calling redis is a style error.  (Consider that you might want to readFiles in some other context and *not* call redis afterwards)

Comment: what I wanted to achieve is just to extract some of the fields from the files(RDF files) and dump them into redis..that's it, but good point, thank you.

Comment: sure, just as FYI, posted a version that most would consider the correct design for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic, promise-returning version of readFiles from the node-dir library.  Notice that its only job is to return a promise that gets resolved when the completion callback is called. Notice that it contains no then block.

```
// a promise returning form of node-dir readFiles
// pass a file handling callback, but no completion function
function readFilesQ(dirname, options, fileCallback) {
  return new Promise((resolved, failed) => {
    // this invocation passes a completion function that resolves the promise
    nodeDir.readFiles(dirname, options, fileCallback, (err, files) => {
      err ? failed(err) : resolved(files)
    });
  })
}
```

Now your file handling and completion logic can be supplied externally, differently based on the context of where you need to read files.

```
readFilesQ(someDirname, someOptions, (err, content, next) => {
  // handle content for each file, call next
}).then(files => {
  // handle correct completion
}).catch(err => {
  // handle error
})
```

Comment: yeah it does make more sense and standard to me